# laplacian of a product of vector and tensor

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, laplacian

given **u** and **v** as two vectors and **T** as a second-order tensor,

we know that the laplacian of a product of two vectors satisfies:
$$\nabla^{2}(\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{v})=\nabla^{2}\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{v}+2\nabla\textbf{u}:\nabla\textbf{v}+\textbf{u}\cdot\nabla^{2}\textbf{v}$$
where $\cdot$ represent inner product and $:$ represent double inner product.

My question is what about the laplacian of a product of vector and tensor?

$$\nabla^{2}(\textbf{u}\cdot\textbf{T})=\ ??$$

$$\nabla^{2}(\textbf{T}\cdot\textbf{u})=\ ??$$

Comment: I only knew for vectors the identity $\nabla^2(\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{B})\ =\ \mathbf{A}{\cdot}\nabla^2\mathbf{B} \,-\, \mathbf{B}{\cdot}\nabla^2\!\mathbf{A}\, +\, 2\nabla {\cdot}\, ((\mathbf{B}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{A} \,+\, \mathbf{B}{\times}(\nabla{\times}\mathbf{A}))$, where did you learn of that identity with the double inner product?, thank you

Comment: from the tensor calculus analysis.